# Display each occurrence of a recurring event in search results

Tags: 2010, search, recurring-events

When you search for a recurring event in search, you only get back one event item whose property for start and end time corresponds to the start time of the first occurrence and the end time of the last occurrence respectively.

Is there any way for search to return all occurrences?
For example, if I have an event that repeats 4 times during the month, I want those 4 occurrences to show up in search with their respective start and end times.

---

<sub>I know for sure that each of those occurrences are actual list items themselves (They have IDs that includes period in them though instead of just a whole number (e.g. *...dispForm.aspx?ID=28.1.31*)). Is it just because that SharePoint doesn't crawl through them?</sub>

Comment: Which kind of item re them? Did your try to run a crawl? Maybe full

Answer (score 5):

I wonder if it is possible to achieve this in OOTB search results. However, i came across a workaround [here](http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2009/06/retreiving-recurring-events-from-a-sharepoint-calendar-list/). It does not use SharePoint Search,instead, it uses CAML query with a property to show recurring events as different item.

The `RecurrenceID` field identifies a specific instance of a recurring event and its value represents the starting date and time of a specific instance.
SPQuery can be used as following in this case:
[image]

So if custom solution is acceptable, the above query can be used to get desired result.

Comment: Yes, I came across that post on my search for a solution. Unfortunately, we're dead set on using search as 1) we don't want to introduce custom code (e.g. custom web part), and b) we want to leverage the querying and the refining done by the OOTB core search results web part.

Comment: Is it possible with JSOM/jQuery and how?